# How do you parse or convert a date range (for a field/cell) in R?

Tags: r, parsing, date, converters

For example,

`dates <- c("25–27 Oct", "25 Oct", "24–25 Oct", "23–24 Oct", "23–24 Oct", 
    "22–23 Oct")`

What is the best way to convert them to a date vector? A desirable outcome would be that we can use them in a dataframe to plot a time series etc.

A solution will either

1. be pragmatic and result in one vector with end dates or
2. list start and end date in two vectors.

Comment: At least give the desirable output! -1 from me!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you store the dates as a list as opposed to a vector (which you create with the `c` function)? If the datatype of all elements is the same, a vector would be more natural.

Comment: Copied out of RStudio, now updated @Backlin.

Comment: My answer already gets you solution number 2. If you store the results in a `data.frame` called `d`, you get start dates by `d$from` and end dates by `d$to`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? In case the date is not an interval, such as `"25 Oct"` you could just as well set `from` and `to` to the same value, but that depends on what you will do with the output.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dates, function(str){
    if(grepl("–", str)){
        data.frame(from=as.Date(sub("–\\d+", "", str), "%d %b"),
                   to=as.Date(sub("\\d+–", "", str), "%d %b"))
    } else {
        data.frame(from = as.Date(str, "%d %b"), to=NA)
    }
}))
```

Output

```
        from         to
1 2013-10-25 2013-10-27
2 2013-10-25       <NA>
3 2013-10-24 2013-10-25
4 2013-10-23 2013-10-24
5 2013-10-23 2013-10-24
6 2013-10-22 2013-10-23
```

Comment: Very nice. I think we should replace the NA with the same date.

Answer (score 1):

What you exactly want to store? The interval or certain date, e.g the middle of interval?

If you don't need interval, then you can try get date with use of gsub or/and strptime()

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html

example:

```
> s="29 Mai"
> strptime(s,format="%d %b")
[1] "2013-05-29"
```

Remember to set apropriate locale time/date to deal with %b

Comment: +1 for the locale , indeed you should use`Sys.setlocale`...